# How do I set/get values of one component from another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**

I have a component (component A) that includes another component (MyColorPicker) within it. I am trying trying to set/get the value of MyColorPicker from component A.

**Problem:**

I am able to set the background color by passing a prop to `MyColorPicker` like so: `<MyColorPicker background="#ff0000" />`.

However, I want to be able to update the background dynamically (i.e. depending on user input) rather than harcoding it into the prop. I also want to be able to get the current background color value in the `handleSubmit` function in Component A.

**Component A Code:**

```
// imports...

function myFunctionA(props) {

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(textOrSelectFields);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <MyColorPicker />
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

**MyColorPicker Code:**

```
// imports...

class MyBlockPicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    background: this.props.background,
  };

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    console.log(color);
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BlockPicker
        color={this.state.background}
        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
        triangle="hide"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyBlockPicker;
```

Any ideas on how to proceed here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `setState` function to the child. If you are using class components you can wrap the `setState` so the child only has access to a limited amount of the state.

i.e.

**In myFunctionA**

```
function myFunctionA(props) {

  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(textOrSelectFields);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <MyColorPicker setSelectedColor/>
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

**In MyColorPicker**

```
class MyBlockPicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    background: this.props.background,
  };

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    console.log(color);
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
    this.props.setSelectedColor(color.hex)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BlockPicker
        color={this.state.background}
        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
        triangle="hide"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyBlockPicker;
```

BTW you are mixing class components and functional components which is going to be a pain as the code base grows...

Comment: Thanks for your help! So to output the value back out from the handleSubmit function, I would simply do `console.log(selectedColor);`, correct? Thanks also for the comment about mixing component types. I will look into cleaning that up.

Comment: If you want to trigger some action (like a console.log) you have two options. One, wrap the `setSelectedColor` in a function, and in that function call perform the console log. Two, create a `useEffect` hook which listens to `slectedColor`, and console.log's when the state changes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how do I access the current value of `MyColorPicker` from within the `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: Oh, `selectedColor` will contain the value after the next render. The (very rough) flow is `setState` -> `render` -> `state is now updated`